# How to create a scheduled post in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to create a posting schedule for my students. I'll post every night at 10 pm. If it's possible with react then fine otherwise I will be ready to use node js and react.

Comment: Your questions is unclear. But based on what i understood, you can use package node-cron to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.